# Phalcon DB block database in order to check it is possible to insert data

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I'm using [Phalcon](http://phalcon.io) and I have a database in MySql. I have three tables in the database:

- user: id, name, sold
- company: id, name, cost
- transactions: id_company, id_user, cost

An user has to do a transaction if has enough money (sold). So I have to do it:

```
Step 1:
retrieve the sold of the user:
select sold
from user
where id='Charlie'

Step 2:
retrive the cost from the company:
select cost
from company
where id='Tango'

Step 3:
to check if the user has enough money:
if (sold-cost >= 0)
create the transaction
else
do not create the transaction.
```

My question is:
Is there a way in order to block the db in order to do the three steps without the db could change?

I would like do this:

```
lock db
step 1
step 2
step 3
unlock db
```

But I have not found a solution for it.

Comment: If you mean you want to make some db changes and if one of them fails you roll back to the original state or if some requirements are met you commit the changes ? Then thats a transaction [read about it here](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models-transactions)

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid that in the same time (or before my unlock) another user could change the table with a update row or delete row. Even in this case could you the Phalcon transaction?

Comment: yes it could happen but that would happen if you have a lot of traffic at the same time. no because servers are made to handle these kind of requests. if you benchmark your code (without html render) you will find it happens in a milliseconds so unless you get hundreds of requests per second then you will be fine. testing is your friend here, you can mimic requests and check what happens

Comment: I'm using Phalcon with VueJs so without rendering by default. But I must be sure that the transaction are safe even a lot of traffic. May I mix $this->db->execute with User::find() and the guide that you have me passed? I suppose that all these methods are safe.

Comment: transactions are for commits only it will not freeze you db your changes will not be in affect until you commit them. so mixing ```execute``` and ```User::find()``` has not effect on each other the db will go back to the original state after rolling back and you will need to refresh the results after that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it implemented in Phalcon framework, but PDO extension implements transactions that can be helpful here:

```
<?php
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select sold from user where id= ?');
$stmt->execute(['Charlie']);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sold = $row['sold'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select cost from company where id= ?');
$stmt->execute(['Tango']);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$cost = $row['cost'];

printf("Sold: %d, Cost: %d", $sold, $cost);

if ($sold >= $cost) {
    //reduse user sold
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('update user set sold = sold - ? where id= ?;');
    $stmt->execute([$cost, 'Charlie']);

    // write transaction
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('insert into transactions values (?, ?, ?);');
    $stmt->execute(['Charlie', 'Tango', $cost]);
    $pdo->commit();
} else {
    $pdo->rollBack();
}


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select * from transactions');
$stmt->execute();
$transactions = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($transactions);
```

[PHP PDO fiddle here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=874105f79d14ee50a13096fbbc58403d&sqlses=d6a562deababe07432938a7f3c9e1a42&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)